# Names of the columns in R

Tags: r

I have a table of locations and values for Precipitation of each month.

I need to add a new column with **name** of the month that has the maximum Precipitation for each location.

I tried to do that:

```
cbind(rainfall, max_month = apply(rainfall[,3:11],1,which.max))
```

but I'm getting only the number of the column and I need the name of the column. 
I got this :

```
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
 [59] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
[117] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4
```

I tried to add the **names** function and the **colnames** function' but both of them didnt help.

```
names(apply(rainfall[,3:11],1,(which.max)))
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You need `apply(df, 1, function(i) names(i[which.max(i)]))`. However, check the function `max.col`

Comment: Could you make your answer reproducible? This will make it a lot easier to help you, especially with providing you with alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something along the lines of:

```
names(rainfall[,3:11])[apply(rainfall[,3:11],1,which.max)]
```

Here you transform the column id to a name by subsetting the `names(rainfall)` vector. Note that repeating an index, e.g. `c(5, 5, 5, 5)` repeats the extracted value.

---

An alternative approach using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mtcars)
mtcars %>% 
    gather(month, precip_value, disp, hp, drat, wt) %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>% 
    summarise(max_month = month[which.max(precip_value)])
```

Note that this approach uses the `mtcars` dataset as your example was not reproducible. Here, `gear` would be your station id. The trick is to restructure the data a bit from wide to long format using `gather`, then splitting the data per station using `group_by` and then determining the max month using `summarise`. Just food for thought, the answer of @sotos is quite elegant.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 4):

Best way to this is via `max.col`. You should always avoid `apply` on data.frames,

```
names(rainfall)[max.col(rainfall[3:11])]
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this function. There is always more to learn in R :).